# Can I create a MATLAB library in C?

Tags: c, matlab

I've got an idea to recreate the MATLAB functions in C using the GNU GSL library and making it available to the public. Am I allowed to do this? Or are there copyright or other restrictions from using MATLAB code that prevent me from doing this?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the responses, I've created the library, it doesn't use any other math library to make it simpler. View it here: https://github.com/martinn16/matlab2c

Comment: Are you aware of [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)?

Comment: AS far as I know to run Matlab function sin C you need the Matlab libraries installed in the computer running it.

Comment: Or, Are you aware of [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about copyright/legal issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MATLAB Terms of Use, Mathworks explicitly disclaims having any rights to source code you wrote yourself using MATLAB or related products. You (or employer) have rights to all creative contributions you originate.

In return for paying for an authorized copy of MATLAB Compiler or MATLAB Coder, Mathworks licenses use of their library and technologies to you, with you having the right to distribute the compiled code for whatever fee you choose -- whether that be no cost, or minimal cost, or full commercial product pricing. Some restrictions may apply (USA export control laws must be satisfied.)

If you, for example, want to create a function with a prototype plot(X,Y) that creates a graph based on two vectors (X and Y) but don't use any Mathworks source or libraries to do so, then it is your own original work and you can do with it as you please.